# Fix SQL Server identity and restore the proper numeration order

Tags: sql-server, database, sequence, identity

I have SQL Server 2014 restarted unexpectedly and that broke straight auto-increment identity sequences on entities. All new entities inserted to tables have their identities incremented by 10 000.

Let's say, if there were entities with IDs "1, 2, 3" now all newly inserted entities are like "10004, 10005".

Here is real data:

```
..., 12379, 12380, 12381, (after the restart) 22350, 22351, 22352, 22353, 22354, 22355
```

(Extra question here is why has it inserted the very first entity after the restart with 22350? I thought it should have been 22382 as it's the latest ID by that moment 12381 + 10001 = 22382)

I searched and found out the reasons for what happened. Now I want to prevent such situations in the future and fix the current jump. It's a production server and users continuously add new stuff to the DB.

**QUESTION 1**

What options do I have here?

My thoughts on how to prevent it are:

1. Use sequences instead of identity columns
2. Disable T272 flag, reseed identity causing it started from the latest right value (I guess there is such an option)

What are the drawbacks of the two above? Please advise some new ways if there are.

**QUESTION 2**

I'm not an expert in SQL Server. And now I need to normalize and adjust the numeration of entities since it's a business requirement. I think I need to write a script that updates wrong ID values setting them to be right. Is it dangerous to update identity values? Some tables have dependent records. What does this script may look like?

**OTHER INFO**

Here is how my identity columns declared (got this using "Generate scripts" option in SSMS):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    ...
    [TaskNo] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Tasks] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I also use Entity Framework 6 for database manipulating.

I will be happy to provide any other information by request if needed.

Comment: Is there some reason you need your identity column values to be sequential rather than just unique and auto-incrementing? What happens if a record is deleted, should the IDs all be recalculated?

Comment: The drawback of trace flag 272 is a performance hit. They made this change to enable SQL Server to cache identity values, so there's less of a hotspot ensuring perfectly contiguous numbers by locking. If you have a business need for something like this (and if possible, you really *shouldn't*, as uniqueness should be enough), use a `SEQUENCE` with an explicit `NO CACHE` (which is more or less what the identity was before explicit sequences were introduced).

Comment: @Diado There is no need to recalculate all other IDS. I mean if we delete an entity with ID 5, it's okay to have the sequence like this `1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8`. The reason I need this to be sort of sequential is that the users rely on this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert How big is potential performance hit if I disable this flag? I guess my DB is not that highly loaded. I estimate approximated load is like inserting 1 record in 10 seconds or so. I think this way may be the easiest on how to solve this issue.

Comment: "Measure and see" is the only correct answer, but with 1 insert in 10 seconds it's safe to say you won't notice. The biggest problems are 1) this trace flag is a global thing (can't opt out or in depending on database), 2) you or your successor will forget that this is necessary and see it break when you upgrade servers, 3) if one day MS decides that they don't want to support this flag anymore, you have to come up with a permanent fix *then*, even though tools for solving the problem in a more permanent way are already available. Your choice whether to kick that can down the road.

Comment: @kseen - "The reason I need this to be sort of sequential is that the users rely on this.". That sounds weird to me. Why are the identity bales being exposed to users at all?

Comment: @BenThul That is weird but users sometimes use these IDs to work on their projects (like they can discuss like "hey take a look at the task 123 I've finished, only task 456 is left to finish the whole project").

Comment: Okay. But what does that have to do with the identity values being gapless?

Comment: First, make sure you are ordering by the field when you select. The values might actually be there. Secondly, I still haven't seen a reason that these need to be gapless.

Comment: If it's a business requirement, then you should estimate the effort (it's not trivial, it has some risk of failure, and it might require downtime). I suspect it might be less of a business requirement once the effort is understood.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once in a weekend of downtime and ended up having to reseed the whole table, by turning off the identity insert and then updating each row with a row numbers. This was based on the tables correct sort order to make sure the sequence was correct.

As it updated the whole table, (500 million rows) it generated a hell of a lot of transaction log data. Make sure you have enough space for this and presize the log if required.

As said above though, if you must rely on the identity column then amend it to a sequence. Also, make sure your rollback mechanism is good if there is an error during insert and the sequence has all ready been incremented.

Comment: I don't think I need to update all table IDs. I would just update the wrong IDs created after the restart. You said "your rollback mechanism is good" how did you write your script to have it good? Could you provide some code, please?